# QItemDelegate: setModelData not firing at correct time

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am trying to create a delegate that will display a button in my table. When the user clicks the button, a dialog will open where the user will be able to input data.

When the dialog is closed, I want it to then update my model.

Everything works except that `setModelData` gets fired **when I click** the push button instead of **when I close the dialog**. I tried creating a custom `dialog_has_been_closed` function that would emit the `commitData` signal, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I stop `setModelData` from firing when I click the push button, and instead get it to fire when I close the dialog?

```py
class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QPushButton(parent)
        editor.dialog = MyValueEditingDialog()
        editor.dialog.accepted.connect(self.dialog_has_been_closed)
        editor.clicked.connect(editor.dialog.show)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.dialog.set_dialog_values(index.data())

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)
        super().paint(painter, option, index)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if editor.dialog.result() == QDialog.Accepted:
            data = editor.dialog.get_editor_default_values()
            model.setData(index, data)

    # Although this gets triggered at the correct time, the commitData signal doesn't seem to do anything
    def dialog_has_been_closed(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        self.commitData.emit(editor)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the view normally tries to update the data whenever it loses focus, which is exactly what happens when the dialog appears (since the window containing the view loses focus, the views loses it too).

A possibility would be to *reset* the `result()` of the dialog as soon as the value has been set:

```py
class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    ...
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QPushButton(parent)
        editor.dialog = MyValueEditingDialog(parent)
        editor.dialog.accepted.connect(lambda: self.commitData.emit(editor))
        editor.clicked.connect(editor.dialog.open)
        return editor

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if editor.dialog.result() == QDialog.Accepted:
            data = editor.dialog.get_editor_default_values()
            editor.dialog.setResult(QDialog.Rejected)
            model.setData(index, data)
```

Note that I added the `parent` argument to the dialog (which should also be implemented in its `super().__init__(parent)`), and changed its `show` to `open` in order to make it modal.

Also be aware that calling `openPersistentEditor` within a `paintEvent()` is **wrong**. The fact that Qt is "smart" enough to ignore the call if the editor is already opened is irrelevant: an editor can potentially change the size hint of the index, which could result in multiple (or even infinite) recursive calls. `paintEvent()` should always **only** draw contents and ***NEVER*** do anything that could trigger itself again (like adding widgets, which immediately requires a repaint).

The *proper* way to ensure that all indexes automatically have a persistent editor opened is to create a function that opens the persistent editor, call it when the view has a new model set (in case it already has contents), and connect the model `rowInserted` signal to that same function.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. Another problem was that in my original code, `self.sender()` was referring to the dialog, and not the editor.

Do you have an example of the alternate approach to `openPersistentEditor` that you've described?

Comment: @AndrewPlowright It's quite simple: create a function that opens a persistent editor given a specific index (or eventually a row or row/column combination) and call `openPersistentEditor()` with that index. Call that function near the end of the `__init__` for each existing index (unless you're completely sure that the model is empty at that time). Then, connect to the `rowsInserted` signal of the model, and call that function with the arguments provided by that signal.